# How to copy a formula horizontally across 9 columns that references 9 row in another sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm in a summary tab and want to enter the data horizontally from another tab that has the data presented vertically.  I'm running a computation on the data.

In my summary tab this is what I want:

```
Column B formula = ProductA!M2/ProductA!N2
Column C formula = ProductA!M3/ProductA!N3
Column D formula = ProductA!M4/ProductA!N4
```

This goes on through column J.

Is there any easy way to enter the formula in column B and copy across for columns C - J?  In the other tabs It's always M/N, starting with row 2 and going through row 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX():

```
=INDEX(ProductA!$M:$M,Column(B:B))/INDEX(ProductA!$N:$N,Column(B:B))
```

The `Column(B:B)` returns 2 in the row criterion of the INDEX the first time then when dragged over the next becomes `Column(C:C)` or 3 for the 3rd row and so on.

Comment: You have an extra `(` before the second `INDEX`.  Won't let me edit since just one character.